# Programmatically Configure a new Product in Magento setting up a custom entity_id

Tags: php, magento, entity-attribute-value

```
#$obj (stdClass Object), $obj->products_id = given int value

$product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($obj->products_id);
$product->setId($obj->products_id); //not working, the session is cancelled
$product->setEntityId($obj->products_id); //not working, the session is cancelled
$product->setProductId($obj->products_id); //working but in "catalog_product_entity" the "entity_id" is created using the auto-increment (from the last registered ID)
//-------------------------------------------------
$product->save();
//-------------------------------------------------
$product->getId(); //loading the "entity_id"
$product->getProductId(); //loads the product id
```

What I want to do is.. load the $obj->products_id into the "entity_id" ("catalog_product_entity").

Any suggestions?! 
The same logic has been applied for "catalog/category" and it worked but on "catalog/product" is not working..

Thank You

Comment: Not sure what you are tyring to do here. If you load the product with $obj->products_id then you don't have to setId as it'll already be set if the product has loaded ok.
I don't think MAgento will allow you to change a product ID once the model is loaded either, it should be immutable.

Comment: If the id field is AUTOINCREMENT then you can't pick a custom id. Why would you want to anyway? Just use the SKU as your custom ID field and let MySQL decide the entity_id to ensure it's unique.